# i have a error when linking, can't fix it myself

Tags: c, assembly, linker, operating-system, ld

ok so, im linking a bootloader, kernel and linker (so i can make a functional os)
i keep getting this when im trying to link:
"ld:linker.ld:4: non constant or forward reference address expression for section .=0x0100000"
the linker:

```
ENTRY (loader)
SECTIONS {

    .=0x00100000;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000): {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        sbss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *.(bss)
        ebss = .;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the ld command line you're executing...

Comment: ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin loader.o kernel.o

Comment: Apparently you need spaces around the `=`. Try `. = 0x00100000;`